# How to INSERT simultaneously two different arrays in PDO MySQL?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, pdo

I'm having trouble with a PDO insert.
I'd like to insert a multidimensional array into a db, which i managed to.
However, i also would like to insert a completely different array, disconnected from the first one into the same db line (which means same INSERT query).
1st multidimensional array = $_POST['training']
2nd array = $training_diploma
Kinda difficult to explain. Here is the code :

```
$id = "1";
$training_diploma = ("master", "bachelor");
$id_training_key = $id_training_key = $id.'_'.$training_diploma; (return: 1_master)

$sql = "INSERT INTO users_resumes (id,resume_category,id_training_key,training_diploma,training_school,training_level,training_start_date,training_end_date) VALUES ($id,'Training',$id_training_key,:training_diploma,:training_school,:training_level,:training_start_date,:training_end_date)";
$stmt= $pdo->prepare($sql);
foreach($_POST['training'] as $params){
   $stmt->execute($params);
}
```

Any help is very welcome !!! Thx a looot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate the `$training_diploma` array as well as the `$_POST` array. It would be better to also include the `id` and `id_training_key` as parameters in your query so you don't have to prepare a new query for each set of values:

```
$id = "1";
$training_diploma = array("master", "bachelor");

$sql = "INSERT INTO users_resumes (id,resume_category,id_training_key,training_diploma,training_school,training_level,training_start_date,training_end_date) VALUES (:id,'Training',:id_training_key,:training_diploma,:training_school,:training_level,:training_start_date,:training_end_date)";
$stmt= $pdo->prepare($sql);
foreach($_POST['training'] as $params) {
    foreach ($training_diploma as $diploma) {
        $stmt->execute(array_merge($params, array('id' => $id, 'id_training_key' => $id . '_' . $diploma)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Works so well this way ! Thanks a lot @Nick !